# google maps movcamera

Tags: javascript, maps

Existe alguma função do googmaps em javascript igual á função movecamera do android, onde ele começa em uma latitude que no caso eu coloco do país,e depos ele dá um zoom em uma latitude que eu coloco da cidade?

Answer (score 0):

Roberto, a documentação da Api do Google é bem rica. Verifique no link abaixo, acredito que tem tudo que você precisa.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Geocoding